# Azure REST API for linking resources(SQLDB,Storage) to Azure cloud service

Tags: azure

Is there any Azure REST API or powershell cmdlets available for linking the resources(SQL DB,Storage)/listing the linked resources to azure cloud services?

Answer (score 0):

No!

And currently (as of 2013-09-17) the feature `linked resource` is just a visual enhancement in the portal. To help you easily get an idea of what components does a cloud service have. Nothing more than that.